# HttpClient accessing a socket application

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I started down the path of using HttpClient as I thought the service I was accessing is a REST service.  Turns out it's a JSON service running on port 80 but is a socket application.

The HttpClient opens the remote port but when it sends the JSON request it never gets a response.  I was having the hardest time getting fiddler to get a response back as well.  But I was able to get wget and curl to send/receiving a response.  That's when I talked to the original developer and he mentioned that it wasn't a true "REST" service, but just a socket application that sends/receives JSON.

Is there something I can do to tweak HttpClient to access a socket application or am I going to have to take a step back and use WebSockets?

This is the test code that sends/receives the JSON packet.

```
        private async Task ProcessZone(string szIPAddress)
    {
        string responseData = string.Empty;

        Uri baseAddress = new Uri(@"http://" + szIPAddress + "/player");

        try
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
            {
                var _req = new SendRequest();
                _req.id = "rec-100";
                _req.url = "/stable/av/";
                _req.method = "browse";

                var _json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_req);

                using (var content = new StringContent(_json,Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
                {
                    using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(baseAddress, content))
                    {
                        responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }
                }
            }

            var _Response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(responseData);

            var item = new ZoneInfo();
            item.szIPAddress = szIPAddress;
            item.szZoneName = _Response.result.item.title;
            lstZones.Add(item);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private async Task ProcessZones()
    {

        foreach (var item in ZoneSearch)
        {
            await ProcessZone(item.IPAddress);
        }
    }
```

The connection hangs on this line:

```
using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(baseAddress, content))
```

I should also mention that the code above does work fine on a true rest service...

Comment: Is the code that calls ProcessZone() "proper" async/await (and all the way up), or does something higher in the stack call .Result() or .Wait()?

Comment: Yes, it all works when accessing a real REST service.  But I guess what I'm trying to access is not a REST service but a JSON service running on a socket.  The connection needs to be opened, JSON called and response received, then closed.  I'll edit to include the calling function though.

Comment: You should anyway add .ConfigureAwait(false) to the first await, as you have with the second.  If something higher in the stack calls .Result()/.Wait(), it might deadlock without it.

Comment: Also REST per-se doesn't come into this, but whether and to what extent the service implements the HTTP protocol probably will.

Comment: The odd thing is I can't access the service through fiddler or any of the chrome rest test plugins.  I never get a response back, I see the request going out though.  However, with CURL I get a full response.

Comment: JSON over port 80 sans HTTP...just when you think you've heard it all.

Comment: That's what I was thinking as well...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> That's when I talked to the original developer and he mentioned that it wasn't a true "REST" service, but just a socket application that sends/receives JSON.

Knowing the protocol is the first step towards making a working client.

> Is there something I can do to tweak HttpClient to access a socket application or am I going to have to take a step back and use WebSockets?

Neither, unfortunately. `HttpClient` - as the name implies - only works with HTTP services. Since the server is not an HTTP server, it won't work with `HttpClient`. WebSockets have a rather confusing name, since they are *not* raw sockets but instead use the WebSocket protocol, which require an HTTP handshake to set up. Since the server is not an HTTP/WebSocket server, it won't work with WebSockets.

Your only choices are to either pressure the developer to write a real REST service (which makes your job orders of magnitude easier), or use raw sockets (e.g., `Socket`). Correctly using raw sockets is extremely difficult, so I recommend you pressure the developer to write a REST service like the entire rest of the world does today.

Comment: Thank you; that's what I needed to know.  I agree, It's so much easier to code against REST.  But I do have experience in sockets as well.  It won't be as pleasant as I'll have to write the threading on my own, but it will be what I have to do.  I don't think I'll have much luck convincing him to re-write to REST; sadly.  The service is a C++ service running on a linux variant so it would be a fair amount of work with no incentive for him. :(